# Angularjs - Firebase display current logged in user's data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase

I am trying to build a mobile shoping application by ionic. I want to show items which user added into its cart. But couldn't find any way by searching in internet.
Can anyone please help?

app.js

```
.constant('FURL', 'https://ecommayakkabi.firebaseio.com/')
```

controller.js

```
.controller('CartCtrl', function ($scope, $state, $cordovaOauth, $localStorage, $location, $http, $ionicPopup, $firebaseObject, Auth, FURL, Utils, basket) {
    var ref = new Firebase(FURL); --
    var user=ref.getAuth();
    if (user==null){
        console.log ('Should log in ');
        $state.go('login');
    } else {
        console.log ('loged ' + user.password.email);
        // can show here user's basket items but how?
    } 
});
```

services.js

```
  .factory("basket", function($firebaseArray) {
      var itemsRef = new Firebase("https://ecommayakkabi.firebaseio.com/items");
      return $firebaseArray(itemsRef);
  })
```

app.js

```
.state('tab.cart', {
    url: '/cart',
    cache: false,
    views: {
        'tab-cart': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/tab-cart.html',
            controller: 'CartCtrl'
        }
    }
});
```

[firebase view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwAok.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Firebase uses denormalized data pattern, you need to write items to the `/items/:userId` , so you will be able to retrieve them by the user id without iterating over all `/items` path and it will be Firebase-rules-friendly.

So, in the place where you do add new items to the `items/` path change it to the:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://ecommayakkabi.firebaseio.com");
var userId = ref.getAuth().uid;
ref.child("items").child(userId).push(yourItemIsThere);
```

and then you can retrieve it via:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://ecommayakkabi.firebaseio.com");
var userItems = $firebaseArray(ref.child("items").child(user.uid));
```

You will aso need to add the according change to the Firebase rules to allow access to the `items/:userId` path only to the users with the according id, its optional part, but without that your app will be insecure.

Example Firebase rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": false,
    "items": {
      "$userId": {
        ".write": "auth.uid === $userId",
        ".read": "auth.uid === $userId"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

According to your comments, the full code for the adding part is:

```
var ref = new Firebase(FURL);
ref.child("items").child(user.uid).push({
  "email": user.password.email,
  "userId": user.uid,
  "product_id": "productId",
  "product_name": "product_name",
  "product_url": "product_url",
  "product_color": "product_color",
  "product_size": "product_size",
  "product_count": "product_count",
  "product_price": "product_price"
});
```

or if you do want to use $firebaseArray there:

```
var ref = new Firebase(FURL);
var userBasket = $firebaseArray(ref.child("items").child(user.uid));
userBasket.$add({
  "email": user.password.email,
  "userId": user.uid,
  "product_id": "productId",
  "product_name": "product_name",
  "product_url": "product_url",
  "product_color": "product_color",
  "product_size": "product_size",
  "product_count": "product_count",
  "product_price": "product_price"
});
```

Comment: I add into items by below code.  `$scope.items.$add({
        "email": user.password.email,
        "userId": user.uid,
        "product_id":"productId",
        "product_name":"product_name",
        "product_url":"product_url",
        "product_color":"product_color",
        "product_size":"product_size",
        "product_count":"product_count",
        "product_price":"product_price"
      }); `  so how can i format this code for using your logic `ref.child("items").child(userId).push(yourItemIsThere);` How i can define information in yourItemIsThere here? I don't know use push function.

Comment: @arslan I did update the answer with the full code example, take a look.

Comment: @arslan Did you try the full code of the adding part, did it work for you?

Comment: sorry for late reponse. Yes i just try and it worked amazing. As you said , it put items under related uid. And also i am able to pull items for current user. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @arslan Great! So, since it is working now, can you accept the answer?

Comment: i just did. Thanks a lot again